# Differences in these subclass definitions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, class

Could someone explain what is the difference between the following class definitions derived from `BaseClass` and in what cases it would matter how they are defined:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...

    def as_dict(self):
        # ...


class SomeClass(BaseClass):

    def as_dict(self):
        # Does this somehow change the method compared to 'AnotherClass.as_dict()' below
        return super(SomeClass, self).as_dict()


class AnotherClass(BaseClass): pass

SomeOtherClass = BaseClass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you add an `as_dict` method to `SomeClass` that contains a *single* `super` call,  there's no difference in the end behavior for that class. There's a difference in the fact that, overall, you've added a couple more function calls that are not necessary.

`AnotherClass` behaves just like `SomeClass` since `SomeClass` doesn't do anything different in `as_dict`. It inherits the methods of `BaseClass` as usual.

`SomeOtherClass` is simply *another name* for `BaseClass`, you aren't creating a subclassing relationship there, just attaching another name by which you can refer to that class.

Comment: Thanks, and if the derived class is not adding anything new, which is the recommended way to go? `AnotherClass` or `SomeOtherClass`?

Answer (score 0):

This is using `BaseClass` with a different name.

```
class AnotherClass(BaseClass): pass
```

---

**This is using `BaseClass` but modifying the method "`as_dict`".** Inside the `as_dict` method, you can do anything (ie.modify the parameters sent to this method) then run the usual function of the `as_dict` method with `super(SomeClass, self).as_dict()`

```
class SomeClass(BaseClass):
    def as_dict(self):
        # Does this somehow change the method compared to 'AnotherClass.as_dict()' below
        return super(SomeClass, self).as_dict()
```

---

**This is simply assigning `BaseClass` to `SomeOtherClass`**, which means they can use `BaseClass` through both keywords.

```
SomeOtherClass = BaseClass
```

Comment: "This is using BaseClass with a different name" but this isn't the case; `AnotherClass` is a subclass of `BaseClass`, `SomeOtherClass` is another name for `BaseClass`.